# Character encoding while parsing a file with Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, encoding, utf-8

With a java script, I am trying to read a file that contains the name of a file on my Linux filesystem. It points to a file that was generated on a Windows OS and has accents in it's name.

Example of this kind of file "input.csv" :

```
MYFILE_tést.doc;1
```

The java program parses the file in question and verifies if that file exists. But for those lines containing accents, `file.exists()` in Java always returns false.

- The file "input.csv" is generated in Windows and encoded in ISO-8859-1
- Linux locales are configured like this :

> ```
>    LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1
>    LC_CTYPE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_TIME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_COLLATE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_MONETARY="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_PAPER="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_NAME="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.ISO-8859-1"
>    LC_ALL=en_US.ISO-8859-1
> ```

- When reading the CSV file in java, i'm forcing the encoding :

  > csvFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
  >   FileInputStream(FILE_CSV), "ISO-8859-1"));

I tried switching to UTF-8 (OS locales + file encoding) or playing with the `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` JVM parameter but still the same problem.

The problem doesn't ocur if i hardcode the filename with the accents in the source code instead of reading it in the csv file.

Any ideas of how to fix this ?

Thank you for your help